# Android Ad-mob not displaying in project?

Tags: admob

I made 2 project and both project contain same credential of ads and code. 
They are working and google ads are showing by both project.

Now I add same code in my old project but ads is not working and "Error code 0" found all the time.

Code is same and credential of apps are same.

Is there any method that i can get the bug that why I got error code 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378933/6096821

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal : My credential is working in example project and many other project too but same implementation is not working in my another project

Comment: Have you linked your app play store app in the admob account?

Comment: Because you have to create different different placements for each application

Comment: but my same credential work in 3 application and all ads are showing smoothly yes I know we have to make diff ID for diff Project but i just want to check weather code is working fine or not